# How to define a relationship between two tables from different sources with different identifiers

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

### Background:

I'm working on a project that does not allow me to share the data, but I'll do my best to give you some visualisation below. So before going further, I know (some) SQL, and I have done basic work relationship before, but the data was clean and simple and for some reason I just can't' figure out a solution.

### Problem (?)

I'm trying to define a relationship between two tables from two different sources that each work with different identifiers. I do have however a mapping table from one of those but again the identifiers do not align. Let me try explain visually:

```
| TABLE 1 (cies)   |      | TABLE 2 (forms)    |
| ------------     |      | -------------      |
| id(PK)           |      | id(PK)             |
| 4_digit_code     |      | 16_digit_code      | 
| ...more fields   |      | ...more fields     |
```

The second source provided me a mapping table they use internally:

```
| MAPPING TABLE    |
| -------------    |
| id(PK)           |
| 4_digit_code     | (= to the one in TABLE 1)
| 16_digit_code    | (= to the one in TABLE 2)
```

My first thought was to create a script and just merge the info in the mapping table in TABLE 1 like so:

```
| TABLE 1          |      | TABLE 2            |
| ------------     |      | -------------      |
| id(PK)           |      | id(PK)             |
| 16_digit_code    | ==== | 16_digit_code      | 
| 4_digit_code     |
```

The issue here is the 16_digit_code is not unique so I believe this does not work. Now comes something I have no experience with so I am just thinking out loud here:

Can I keep (?) the mapping table and each time reference that one to get my data from the other table via another? On other hand should not all values in a mapping table be unique as well for it to work? The reason there are non-unique values is that (some) very old numbers end up getting recycled.

For example get me all forms from company with id 1:

```
| TABLE 1          |      | MAPPING TABLE      |      | TABLE 2            |
| ------------     |      | -------------      |      | -------------      |
| id(PK)           |      | id(PK)             |      | id(PK)             |
| 16_digit_code    |      | 16_digit_code      | ==== | 16_digit_code      | 
| 4_digit_code     | ==== | 4_digit_code       |      | ...more fields     |
```

And in the above, I would not know how to efficiently approach this problem. I really don't know if it makes any sense though what I am saying or I am missing something or making this way too complex.

### Solution?

I'd love it if someone could point me in the right direction. And if you have the solution I'd love to know the reasoning, not just the solution as I'd love to learn from this for the future obviously.

### Edit/Clarification:

Just for completion sake, the mapping combination (4 digit + 16 digit code) is unique. Although, as I said earlier one 16 digit code can be linked to multiple 4 digit codes.

Comment: Your problem can be easily solved with joins, but since 16_digit_code is not unique you would get more that 1 rows from table2 for each row of table1.

Comment: Is the combination of the 4 and 16 digit code unique?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If you meant in the mapping table then no. For example I found some instances where the same 16 digit code is linked to as many as 58 different 4 digit codes, although those are rare.

In fact a large majority has a unique 1-on-1 entry in mapping table (8984 unique 16 digit codes for 11465 4 digit codes).

Comment: Still not clear whether the combination of 4 + 16 is unique or not? Are the 4 letter codes unique? What is the purpose of this exercise; to create unique rows, to find non-unique rows, something else?

Comment: The 4 digit codes are unique, there are no duplicates. If I understand your question correctly I believe the answer is yes. For one 4 digit + 16 digit combo there no other. They are unique.

The purpose would be to simply allow a search to show me all forms linked to a given company or vice versa. Ultimately there are a ton of other queries to run but this is the basic most important behaviour I need.

Comment: So what defines a company, the `id`, `code_4`, `code_16` or combination thereof?

Comment: Well for me and the first data source it is the id in company table. For the data source that provided me with the second table, it is the 16 digit code. They don't care about any other info. They just have a legal entity defined through a 16 digit code.

You should look at it like table 1 contains data in a universal, industry accepted & structured format while table 2 is basically something that one company worked with internally. Now I just need to make both talk.

Comment: You can *easily* share data just use RANDOM to generate some numbers then manually manipulate them then to give what you are trying to describe, or just use the numeric pad. The sample data does not have to be actual.  So please post sample data and the expected results.